# Prepared Statement getting Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have read everything I can think of to get an explanation but nothing seems to help. If someone might be able to point out the obvious or give me a slight idea of what is wrong. I have read through php.net and the `mysqli` tag and can't seem to figure this out. Everything I read says you can't send two queries but I am only trying one. Any help would be much appreciated.

This->https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649149/1626329 - States that maybe I have multiple result sets but I am not sure that makes much sense or what I can do to get more detail on the inner workings of prepared statements.

My Code:

```
class mydb {

    public function __construct() {
        // Connect to Database
        $this->mydb = new mysqli('****', '***', '***', '***');
        if ($this->mydb->connect_errno) { // Error on connection failure
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL in Construct: (" . $this->mydb->connect_errno . ") " . $this->mydb->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function choose ($select, $from, $config = 0, $options = NULL) {
        if ($config === 0) { /** Configure statement for prepare depending on options */
            $stmt = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM ' . $from;
        } elseif ($config === 1) {
            $stmt = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM ' . $from . ' WHERE ' . $options['where_comp'] . ' LIKE ?';
        } elseif ($config === 2) {
            $stmt = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM ' . $from . ' WHERE ' . $options['where_comp'] . ' = ?';
        } /** End if/elseif Prepare statemenet */
        $mydb = $this->mydb->prepare($stmt);
        if ($config === 1 || $config === 2) {
            $mydb->bind_param("s",$options['where_value']);
        }

        if ($mydb->execute()) { /** If execute is good then get results */
            $result = $mydb->get_result();
            $payload = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                $payload[] = $row;
            }
            return $payload;
        } /** End if results */
    } /** End choose class method */
} /** End mydb Class */

$myDB = new mydb();

$agentArray = $myDB->choose('*','`agent`');
```

Used the php.net example and modified it to show a better example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'database', 'user', 'pass');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM ?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
    echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

for ($row_no = ($res->num_rows - 1); $row_no >= 0; $row_no--) {
    $res->data_seek($row_no);
    var_dump($res->fetch_assoc());
}
$res->close();
```

Comment: You cannot use table name or column name as parameter, that's the first thing I noticed.

Comment: just found one error: `$payload[] .= $row;` should be `$payload[]= $row;` (the dot `.` removed)

Comment: Arg I wish that was more apparent in the documentation. Maybe i just missed the whole purpose of prepared statements or I am sanitizing things that are not user input. Time to rethink this whole class LOL - THanks Guys!

Comment: Also, class constructors should not return anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding an if statement to show the error correctly actually gives a mysql error response that can be used:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM ?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Error response:
`Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`

-- You can't pass identifiers through prepared-statements and you should only use it for values passed from user input.

Comment: I was supplying the correct answer for anyone else to view since your suggestion of the answer was incorrect. This is the way I could have seen an issue before even doing the execute that returned the result I showed above. I was under the impression that if my issue did not apply to all the examples that I should show examples of what caused my problem at a later step when the error did not show in debugging. Its very disappointing to see me losing rep for actually explaining the issue in detail. I was not trying to steal the credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

The very first result from the "Related" section on this page (Means it was offered to you while you were in struggle writing your question) [offers a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now?rq=1).

As a general rule, it is quite easy to find an answer to a question based on the error message. Only you need is not to stop at the very first search result but proceed a bit more.

However, on this function `choose()` of yours. I find it quite impractical, unsafe, and useless:

- impractical because it doesn't let you to use SQL, but a very limited subset of it.

  - and also it makes your code extremely hard to understand.
- unsafe because it does offer no protection for all the dynamical parts but where value only
- useless because it can save you not that much to worth a mess.

Look, you think you saved yourself 2 words - `SELECT` and `FROM`.

```
 $agentArray = $myDB->choose('*','`agent`',1,
               array('where_comp' => 'name', 'where_value' -> "%bob%"));
```

yet you made this code hard to understand, hard to maintain and unable to run ever simplest JOIN. Why not to make it. Not to mention that actual code become **longer** than conventional SQL query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `agent` WHERE name LIKE ?';
$agentArray = $myDB->query($sql, "%bob%");
```

which one is easier to read?

Comment: Viewing the scope of it right now looks very useless but I assure you in the long run it will make more sense. I am not a fan of joins and my system is designed to avoid that but that is a very valid point that I will keep in mind. The idea of a class is in essence to write "unreasonable or limited code that works" and then easily be able to change the format later and not recode the entire site. Another reason I posted this code is to see other angles that people that have been coding for a while normally use instead. Thank you for the insight!